# NullPointerException a PrepareStatement

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

da error en la segunda linea luego del try, desconozco si es por como se conecto "con" con conn pero a lo que se conexionBD si funciona correctamente.

Lo unico que se me ocurre que da error es justo con=conn.conexionB.

````
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ConexionBD conn = new ConexionBD();
        Connection con = conn.ConexionB();
        
        Vector<Familia> datos = new Vector<Familia>();
        Familia dat = null;
        
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT NOMBREFAM FROM FAMILIAS";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            dat = new Familia();
            dat.setId(0);
            dat.setNombre("Seleccione familia:");
            datos.add(dat);
                 
            
            while (rs.next()) {                
            dat = new Familia();
            dat.setId(rs.getInt("idfam"));
            dat.setNombre(rs.getString("familia"));
            datos.add(dat);
            }
            
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());
        } ```
````

Comment: ¿La línea que te falla es la que pone `ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)`? Si es así, entonces la llamada a `Connection con = conn.ConexionB()` falló y parece que te devolvió `null` para indicarlo.

Comment: como lo podria arreglar?

Comment: Habría que investigar el funcionamiento de `conn.ConexionB()`. El error que sufres es consecuencia de un problema estableciendo la conexión, por lo que debes investigar el código que realiza esa función.

Comment: Muestra el error que te debe de lanza el programa en la consola para poder ver cual es error.